# Changing order of double integral

Tags: integration

I have a double integral with the integral with respect to x on the inside between 0 and y^2 and the outer integral with respect to y between 0 and 1. If i change the order of the integrals what would the new limits be for x and y?

Comment: hint: draw the region of integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question you are integrating a function $f(x,y)$ on the set

$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x \in (0, y^2) \wedge y \in (0,1)\}.$$

In order to change the limits of integration, let's work on $x \in (0, y^2)$. $x > 0$, easy. Then $\sqrt{x}$ exists and:

$$x < y^2 \Rightarrow (y < -\sqrt{x} \vee y > \sqrt{x})$$

Since $y \in (0,1)$, then we have:

$$y > \sqrt{x}.$$

Now, when $y=0$, then $\sqrt{x} = 0$ iff $x = 0$. When $y=1$, then $\sqrt{x} = 1$ iff $x = 1$.

At this point your domain $S$ can be rewritten as follow:

$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y \in (\sqrt{x}, 1) \wedge x \in (0,1)\}.$$

You can conclude that:

$$\int_0^1 \int_{0}^{y^2} f(x,y) dxdy = \int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{x}}^1 f(x,y)dydx$$

Answer (score 2):

On the first case, you integrate on

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} f(x,y) dxdy$$

with
$$0 < x < y^2 < 1$$

It's the same as 
$$ 0 < \sqrt{x} < y < 1$$

Hence you want to integrate

$$\int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{x}}^1 f(x,y) dydx$$